# Adding logic to jobs in specific django rq queue

Tags: django, django-rq

I have django-rq set up with multiple workers on three different queues.
I would like jobs done on a **specific queue** to have additional logic after the method is done (basically add `mail_admins` once the job is done).

The only way I found of was to inherit from the `rq.job.Job` class and add this logic there. But `Job` class is set for all queues and not per queue.